# How I can Add struct to ArrayList in C++/CLI

Tags: .net, visual-c++, arraylist, struct, c++-cli

I have the follwoing VC++ code

```
ref struct solution
{
    public :ArrayList ^ cromosom;
    public :int cost;
};

ArrayList players = gcnew ArrayList();
sol1 = gcnew ArrayList();
solution solve;
solve.cost=10;
solve.cromosom = gcnew ArrayList(players);
sol1->Add(solve);
```

An Error occur on `soll->Add(solve);` the error is:

```
cannot convert parameter 1 from 'game::solution' to 'System::Object ^'
```

How i can solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not real C++ but C++/CLI as you are using .NET classes.

Try this:

```
ref struct solution
{
    public :ArrayList ^ cromosom;
    public :int cost;
};

ArrayList players = gcnew ArrayList();
sol1 = gcnew ArrayList();
solution ^solve = gcnew solution;
solve->cost=10;
solve->cromosom = gcnew ArrayList(players);
sol1->Add(solve);
```

Your solution cannot be a stack allocated object!